# How to do multiple substitutions using boost:: regex

Tags: c++, regex, boost

This is my code

```
// replace all new lines with string "nl"
std::string s = "Stack\nover\rflowâ€";
boost::regex expr1("(\\n)|(\\r)");
std::string fmt("nl");
std::string s2 = boost::regex_replace(s, expr, fmt);
```

Then replace all non-ascii characters with empty string

```
boost::regex expr2("([^\x20-\x7E])")
std::string fmt2("");
std::cout << boost::regex_replace(s2, expr2, fmt2) << std::endl;
```

I would rather have one call to replace instead of two.

Comment: I know it doesn't answer directly to your question, but I think you should stay with two separate calls, since these are two separate tasks.

Comment: The response below resolves your question. It would be nice if you flagged it as correct.

Answer (score 6):

This will do it:

```
std::string s = "Stack\nover\rflowâ€";
boost::regex expr("(\\n)|(\\r)|([^\x20-\x7E])");
std::string fmt("(?1nl)(?2nl)"); // Omitted the (?3) as a no-op
std::string s2 = boost::regex_replace(s, expr, fmt, boost::match_default | boost::format_all);
std::cout << s2 << std::endl;
```

See [Boost-Extended Format String Syntax](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_46_1/libs/regex/doc/html/boost_regex/format/boost_format_syntax.html) and [the example](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_46_1/libs/regex/doc/html/boost_regex/ref/regex_replace.html#boost_regex.ref.regex_replace.examples) at the end of the doc for regex_replace.

Comment: Did you test this? On my system this returns unexpected result. Stack(?1nl)(?2nl)over(?1nl)(?2nl)flow(?1nl)(?2nl)(?1nl)(?2nl) Windows 7 VS 2008 Express

Comment: Oops. I forgot the boost::format_all match_flag, which enables the (?Ntext) syntax. I corrected the code and tested it under g++. Sorry.